# How ants handle the huge "data" from multiple pheromone trails?

Tags: ethology, ant, communication

We know that every single ant produces pheromones to communicate and inform others. When there are millions of ants, how do they handle that many signals without getting confused?

Comment: Why expect every signal to be different? Many would be redundant or boosting, along a trail leading to much food or in the presence of predators, for example. Then there's likely a priority system that would let "colony in danger" signals block out everything else.